# Resizing the detail view if popover comes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I am using master detail layout in my application. Every thing works fine, but when i clicked on the menu the popover comes and it is placed above the detail view. like this[image]

actually in the detail view i have some videos displayed, like this..[image]

when the popover come the videos are not visible, how to resize the detail view so that it moves right automatically when popover comes and the details are displayed like in case of landscape mode. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

This is how a `UISplitViewController` works when in portrait orientation. The detail view can't be resized.

However, just before the popover slides into view, the `splitViewController:popoverController:willPresentViewController:` delete method will be called. You could implement this and adjust the views in your detail controller to shift as needed. But this would not be standard behavior.

Comment: can we make the popover to disappear after the user selects an item in that list...

Comment: Sure. You get a reference to the popover in the delegate method I mentioned. Use that reference to dismiss the popover when needed.

Comment: i dismissed the popover using [pc dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; using that method but nothing happened the behavior dint change